# How to make a focused item on an HTML element have its behavior (like click listener) be triggered by pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, html, css, wai-aria

How would i trigger a click event listener based by pressing on enter in keyboard when element is in focus. I know it is doable by using something like button tag where pressing the enter key when it is in focus would act as a click, but what about for something like a div or a p tag. Is there any way to do it without setting up a listener for something like a keydown?

Answer (score 3):

First, if it's not on an input field, you have to make your element focusable (in your example, the DIV or P tag). You have to add a `tabindex="0"`. Then you need an event listener.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("button_div");

ele.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    let a = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode;

 if (a == 13) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert()
 }      
});
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" id="button_div">Click me</div>
```